# Using redux why won't my app state isAuthenticated stay set to true after any kind of reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Using redux for a reactjs app and trying to keep track of users being authenticated or not. For auth state isAuthenticated is set to true but goes back to null if there is a page reload even though the tokens still remain in local storage as the user is still logged in. Check out the code:

here is the store

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
);
```

Here is the reducer and the case where isAuthenticated is set to true:

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: null,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            const access = action.payload.access;
            const refresh = action.payload.refresh;
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refresh);
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
            };
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is where the store is brought in:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
            <BaseRouter/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: The redux/app state is in memory. Upon a page load/reload do you check local storage and repopulate your state?

Comment: @DrewReese would I specifically implement this functionality? If so, no I have not.

Comment: Yes, the reducers only load the initial state defined for each one, but you can pass an initial state object to your root reducer to start with something else, like some state you've persisted to localStorage.